# How can I inject real php code into this website?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

So I found a file uploader on `example.com`. The file uploader accepts every file extension and the file is uploaded inside the directory

`/temp/random-numeric-id.php`

I tried to upload a php file and it got uploaded, however when I access that file, the content of the file is read as html comment. For example, I uploaded a file with content `<?php print(123); ?>` and when I visit `example.com/temp/111111111.php` I see a blank page because my php code has became the following:

`<!--?php print(123); -->`

Is this some kind of protection mechanism? How can I bypass this to execute my print functionality with php on that server?

Comment: Is it a PHP site? Is it set up to even execute PHP code?

Comment: @schroeder,

It's an ajax based website so i think it's allowed to execute php code.  Is it possible that they disabled the execution of PHP inside the temp directory?

Every request from that website is sent with ajax and with the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header. It also supports json and html but no php request in sight.

Comment: "It's an ajax based website so i think it's allowed to execute php code": [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) has nothing to do with php. To your comment below, `<%` is also used by [jsp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) and very probably other templating languages.

Comment: @msanford,

I red that sually AJAX is used with php. Thanks for the info.

Comment: The server is `Apache` based, could it be that they didn't install php on it?

Comment: I would upload a forged `.htacess` if I were you :) This could allow you to reset the way apache handles php script, and drop the protential `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /intermediate-script-that-replaces-php-tags.php?file=$1 [END]` or so this site seems to use. Tho you already have a powerful XSS attack here. And with such way of "securing" their website, I would bet the uploader is vulnerable to path traversal so you can save your file anywhere else you want (say, into `DOCUMENT_ROOT`)

Comment: @Xenos,

The problem is that the file is renamed. So it will became something like `111111.htaccess` and i don't think it will work. Yes at the moment i have a nice XSS but nothing more. I'd like to escalte it to php rce or something like that thou.

Answer (score 5):

This is... strange. My guess is that you are right in that this is some sort of protection mechanism, but it doesn't look like a very stable one. A better approach would be to block files with `.php` or similar extensions, and on top of that turn off PHP execution in that folder.

So can this be exploited, and if so, how? I am not sure, but here are a few things to try:

- Different [PHP tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) (`<?`, `<?=`, `<%`, `<%=`, `<script language="php">`).
- Insert whitespace and try different cases, e.g. `<?PHp` or `<? pHp`. (Not sure if the PHP engine will recognise this, though.)
- Leave out the closing tag, try nesting tags inside tags, and so on.
- Maybe it only does the replacement for PHP files? Then you could use `.php5` or `.phtml` or similar instead.

To figure out a bypass (if there is one), you need to guess how the system works and test your theories. E.g. if you suspect it simply replace all `<` with `<!--`, send in a lone `<` and see what happends! Don't be afraid to experiment. Trial and error is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the advices. So it seems that `<` is accepted as it accepts html tags but when i use `<?` it's changed to `<!--?`, same for `<?=` -
I thought that `<%` was used for ASP filetype only. How can i use it with php code?

`<%` is accepted thou.

also, `<script language="php">` is accepted

While `< pHp` is considered as text/html and printed as text

I already tried with phtml (text) - php3, php4 and php5 gives the same result, the one i already mentioned.

What other could i try?

Comment: It seems that it reads php and html files as `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` regardless of their extension...

I think i should try with other server-side languages, which should i try to use?

Comment: `< pHp` will not be recognized.

Comment: The server is `Apache` based, could it be that they didn't install php on it?

Comment: This is certainly a strange way of trying to protect against RCE. Shame it's impossible to say if there is any vulnerability here.

Comment: @Pong it is entirely possible that PHP is not installed, or the web server is configured to not run PHP files in this directory. I'm either case, this simply won't work. However it is also possible that PHP is installed and will run if you can just bypass this filter. Finding a bypass is the tricky part...

Comment: @Pong `<%` works for PHP in some versions with some configurations. Same for the script tag. If you get them past the filter but they are not executed, it is a sign either that there is no PHP or that it is a newer version.

Comment: @Pong Two further areas to explore: (1) Character encoding (not sure how, sceptical it will work). (2) If `<?` is preserved in e.g. `.txt` files or `.png`, I would think about double extension or null byte injection. This is all very speculative, though.

Comment: @Anders,

Tried to send it as html encoded and i can see `<?php print(123); ?>` printed as text. In `.txt` files is not changed and it leaves it as `<?` - 
With double extension doesn't work as it renames the uploaded file and only keeps the last extension: For example naming it `file.php.jpeeg` will be changed to `11111111.jpeeg`

Will try with null byte injection and let you know. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using a directive based file upload such a self contained htaccess she'll like my htshells project:
https://github.com/wireghoul/htshells